# CORS issue - Restricted access- tried many things

Tags: api, graphql, cors, graphql-js

I am using react-graphql and graphql-request to fetch data however I have an issue with CORS. not sure if I am missing something on the headers I tried different headers as well and not sure what could be the issue now.

The error I am getting is this:

`: localhost has been blocked.request header field credentials is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

So my client.ts

```js
import { GraphQLClient } from "graphql-request";

const endpoint = `https://staging-example-server/graphql/`;

export const graphQlClient = new GraphQLClient(endpoint, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS",
  },
});
```

and here is my queryClient.ts file:

```js
import { QueryClient } from "react-query";

export const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      staleTime: 15000,
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: You need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`  to the headers you want to allow. The error message states exactly what the issue is and what you need to do

Comment: even with that is not working:
"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "http://localhost:3000/",
    "Acess-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",

Comment: You seem to have added Allow Headers twice

Comment: @mousetail thank you for the edit here is the updated code:

  "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Acess-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, x-requested-with, Accept",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "PUT,POST,GET",

Still same error, I thought this should work.. Thank you again

Comment: You need to add the header "credentials" (as the error says) to the allowed headers

Comment: The error message included in your question is not consistent with your client code. You must not be telling us everything. Besides, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` belong in responses, not in requests; including such headers to a request makes no sense.

Comment: @jub0bs aa okey it makes sense yes now the error is gone once I removed those headers..I didnt know..gonna read more about it.. thank you